# Theano support GPU is not working on google Colab

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, theano, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a model based on the Theano library. As my computer havn't enough memory to train this model, I need to do it in Google Colab.
But I can't activate the GPU support of Theano.

This is how I installed Theano and Lasagne

```
!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip
!pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

And here is the way that I try to acctivate the GPU support

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32"
import theano
print(theano.config.__getattribute__('device'))
```

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.7 or higher required)
NoneType: None

cuda
```

I tried to upgrade pygpu using anaconda but anaconda is not installed in Google Collab.

Thanks in advence for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install `condacolab` package:

```py
!pip install -q condacolab

import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

2. After auto restarting kernel do importing `condacolab`:

```py
import condacolab
condacolab.check()
```

3. Install `theano` and `pygpu` packages:

```py
!mamba install -y theano pygpu
```

4. Configurate and import `theano`:

```py
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "device=cuda,floatX=float32"

import theano
print(theano.config.__getattribute__('device'))
```

To test Theano with GPU use [the code from Theano docs](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu).

Answer (score 4):

```
#install conda
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')

#install theano and pygpu
!conda install theano pygpu
```

and you are good to go...

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explaination of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: @Umme Aiman This solution no longer works on google colab. Can you please update the solution and also explain each line. Thanks.